# How to modify tick to dash in css for bootstrap checkbox

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

My task is to modify "tick" inside of the checkbox to "dash". I am new to css and so far I see that I need to modify this bit to have the "dash".
I will appreciate if someone points me to documentation and suggest a solution which parameters can be used to do this.

```
input[type='checkbox'].input-checkbox {

&::before {
    border-bottom: 5px solid $charcoal;
    border-right: 5px solid $charcoal;
    content: '';
    height: 20px;
    left: 9px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transition: $transition-default;
    width: 11px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you can edit that at all, as this is browser native (unless I'm wrong, someone please correct me). The `&::before` is LESS, not CSS, so you won't be able to use that anyway. I'm pretty sure you cannot change the checkbox tick, or the radio dot.

Comment: checkout https://codepen.io/bbodine1/pen/novBm

Comment: There is no way to edit the native feel of the input fields. If you want to change the feel of checkbox, please use input + label  as explained in the following link http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-easy-css3-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons--webdesign-8953

Comment: Try This - [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ghxjoys6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change that I think. What you could do is create a custom checkbox using css or a background image. Wrap the label around the input and set background image to the label. You can then set `opacity: 0` for the input.